# Custom listview with multiple values in a row

Tags: android, listview

im trying to implement a custom listadapter that is set to display only distinct values for each row via the sql query. In each row i want to implement a list of textview values that displays data from another sql query. How can i implement an adapter like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could be a little clear on your question. From what I understand, you want a listview of textviews inside a listview of textviews? More of a nested ListView. If that's the case then you can go for an ExpandableListView like this one:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html